# Is there usually vertical movement between the wing and fuselage?

Tags: airbus-a320

Is there a slight movement in the point of connection of the wing with the fuselage of the Airbus plane in the event of flight and air turbulence?

Comment: Related: [How is a wing joined to the fuselage?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33087/3201) and perhaps: [How strong is the A380 fuselage-wing joint?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9409/3201)

Answer (score 9):

While all structures have some compliance, for all purposes, no.  The wing-body join is going to be an extremely rigid set of fittings with numerous bolts attaching them.

The wing itself is quite flexible.  The wingtip will deflect substantially in flight and the deflection will change in turbulence.

The fuselage is also flexible.  In general, it 'hangs' on the wing -- the aft fuselage droops throughout flight, but also while sitting on the ground.  The forward fuselage is supported by the nose gear on the ground, but droops in flight.

Comment: Could also be Slats, Flaps, Ailerons, control surfaces might give the illusion of movement of the wing ?    Also, subtle movements of the cladding will magnify changes in reflections due to light, looking like additional movement that is quite microscopic ?